# complete list of special characters (e.g \nquit)

Tags: character

I desperatly tried to find out what symbol '\nquit' is... and I couldnt find any reference in the web.

What I tried to find is a complete list of all of those characters (\n, \p, \0, ...) but I couldn't find any.

cheers usche

Comment: Are you sure it's not "\nquit"?  C and its derivatives & variants (C++, Java, C#, JavaScript) enclose a character in single quotes, but a string in double quotes.  In double quotes, this would simply mean a newline (linefeed) character followed by the word "quit".  That is the "quit" would be the first thing on the next line of output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia has a list of C language escapes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart).

As noted in my comment, I believe this represents the newline (linefeed) character `\n` followed by the word `quit` (which would be forced by the newline to the beginning of the next line of output).  But in that case the string should be `"double"`-quoted rather than `'single'`-quoted.